# laravel hide result for all relations if column has specific value

Tags: laravel

Lets assume I have a table `posts` with the fields `id` and `content` and `published`.
A User can have multiple posts, and a post can belong to multiple pages and there might be a lot more relations to a post.

Lets say we have an admin that wants to moderate the posts, the posts should only be visible if approved. So I add the boolean `published` where posts that are not published `0` should never be visible (only in specific cases e.g. to moderate the post).
Is it possible to set something in the `Post` model to restrict the related models from loading non published posts.
I want to avoid that I have to filter in the relation, e.g. if I call `$user->posts` I do not want to check if the posts are published, the non published results should not be available only if i do a search like.  `Post::where('published','0')`. Basically something like softdeletes but than with a custom field.

An example, where the opposite relations are also defined, to make it easier to understand would be:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'posts';


    public function collection()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Collection');
    }

    public function style()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Style');
    }

    public function pictures()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Picture')->orderBy('priority', 'asc');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to show specific field from controller then you can do like that `Post::where('published','0')->get(['id','name])` with select method `Post::where('published','0')-select('id', 'name')->get()`    or if you want to hidden from collection,  you can do like this  `$posts->makeHidden(['address', 'phone_number']);`  or, you can hide from model as `protected $hidden = array('password', 'token');` I dont know above method can solve your problem or not, but it can give you an idea,  so I give this answer as comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use [global query scope](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#global-scopes) in the Model as below to add your desired filters to each query, like below:

```
// Post.php

class Post extend Model
{
    protected static function booted()
        {
            static::addGlobalScope('published', function (Builder $builder) {
                $builder->where('published', true);
            });
        }

// ...
}
```

Whenever you don't want to apply the global query scope, use `withoutGlobalScope` with the name of the query scope, like below:

```
Post::withoutGlobalScope('published')->get();
```